# What is deep linking in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, deep-linking

I was studying AngularJS for interview propose then **deep linking** but i am not able understand why it is used, when it used, and What is the propose of it in angularjs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a clear definition of deep linking from [this blog](http://www.divami.com/blog/deep-linking-angular/):

> Deep linking is the usage of the URL, which will take to specific page
>   (content) directly without traversing application from home page.
>   It helps in getting indexed so that these links can be easily
>   searchable by search engines like Google, Yahoo.. etc.

Using Angular, the deep linking is defaut done with the `#` prefix (when the HTML5 mode is not set).

Answer (score 1):

Hello Friends today i explained the deep linking.
Deep linking is the is a usage of the URL which will tack the specific page Content without traversing application home page. It helps for the indexed so that this link can be easily searchable by the SEO like google yahoo....etc.
There are the four type of linking functions are available in Angular JS named is below.

- Compile
- Controller
- Pre-Link
- Post Link